# Indexing a file with clang-c doesn't hit my ppIncludedFile callback

Tags: compiler-construction, clang

I'm using the Objective-C class below to index an Objective-C file. I've tried parsing files that use both `#include` and `#import`, with both angle-bracket and quoted header files. In no case does my `ppIncludedFile` callback get hit. Clang is clearly including the files as I get index callbacks for the symbols defined in them. But regarding the overall structure, I get `enteredMainFile`, then I get `startedTranslationUnit` for the main file too. But I never find out what header files it's looking in.

According to the documentation:

> /**    * \brief Called when a file gets #included/#imported.    */
>   CXIdxClientFile (*ppIncludedFile)(CXClientData client_data,
>                                       const CXIdxIncludedFileInfo *);

this isn't happening. Is it a bug, or do I need to do something to enable this callback? The version of `libclang` I'm using is from svn trunk r156259.

```
//
//  FZAClassParser.m
//  ObjectiveBrowser
//
//  Created by Graham Lee on 07/05/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Fuzzy Aliens Ltd.. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FZAClassParser.h"
#import "FZAClassParserDelegate.h"

int abortQuery(CXClientData client_data, void *reserved);
void diagnostic(CXClientData client_data,
                CXDiagnosticSet diagnostic_set, void *reserved);
CXIdxClientFile enteredMainFile(CXClientData client_data,
                                CXFile mainFile, void *reserved);
CXIdxClientFile ppIncludedFile(CXClientData client_data,
                               const CXIdxIncludedFileInfo *included_file);
CXIdxClientASTFile importedASTFile(CXClientData client_data,
                                   const CXIdxImportedASTFileInfo *imported_ast);
CXIdxClientContainer startedTranslationUnit(CXClientData client_data,
                                            void *reserved);
void indexDeclaration(CXClientData client_data,
                      const CXIdxDeclInfo *declaration);
void indexEntityReference(CXClientData client_data,
                          const CXIdxEntityRefInfo *entity_reference);

static IndexerCallbacks indexerCallbacks = {
    .abortQuery = abortQuery,
    .diagnostic = diagnostic,
    .enteredMainFile = enteredMainFile,
    .ppIncludedFile = ppIncludedFile,
    .importedASTFile = importedASTFile,
    .startedTranslationUnit = startedTranslationUnit,
    .indexDeclaration = indexDeclaration,
    .indexEntityReference = indexEntityReference
};

@interface FZAClassParser ()

- (void)realParse;

@end

@implementation FZAClassParser
{
    NSString *sourceFile;
    NSOperationQueue *queue;
}

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithSourceFile:(NSString *)implementation {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: implementation]) {
            return nil;
        }
        sourceFile = [implementation copy];
        queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)parse {
    __weak id parser = self;
    [queue addOperationWithBlock: ^{ [parser realParse]; }];
}

- (void)realParse {
#pragma warning Pass errors back to the app
    @autoreleasepool {
        CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(1, 1);
        if (!index) {
            NSLog(@"fail: couldn't create translation unit");
            return;
        }
        CXTranslationUnit translationUnit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, [sourceFile fileSystemRepresentation], NULL, 0, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
        if (!translationUnit) {
            NSLog(@"fail: couldn't compile %@", sourceFile);
            return;
        }
        CXIndexAction action = clang_IndexAction_create(index);
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:willBeginParsingFile:)]) {
            [self.delegate classParser: self willBeginParsingFile: sourceFile];
        }
        int indexResult = clang_indexTranslationUnit(action,
                                                     (__bridge CXClientData)self,
                                                     &indexerCallbacks,
                                                     sizeof(indexerCallbacks),
                                                     CXIndexOpt_SuppressWarnings,
                                                     translationUnit);
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:didFinishParsingFile:)]) {
            [self.delegate classParser: self didFinishParsingFile: sourceFile];
        }
        clang_IndexAction_dispose(action);
        clang_disposeTranslationUnit(translationUnit);
        clang_disposeIndex(index);
        (void) indexResult;
    }
}

@end

int abortQuery(CXClientData client_data, void *reserved) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParserShouldAbort:)]) {
            return [parser.delegate classParserShouldAbort: parser];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

void diagnostic(CXClientData client_data,
                CXDiagnosticSet diagnostic_set, void *reserved) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:foundDiagnostics:)]) {
            [parser.delegate classParser: parser foundDiagnostics: diagnostic_set];
        }
    }
}

CXIdxClientFile enteredMainFile(CXClientData client_data,
                                CXFile mainFile, void *reserved) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:enteredMainFile:)]) {
            return [parser.delegate classParser: parser enteredMainFile: mainFile];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

CXIdxClientFile ppIncludedFile(CXClientData client_data,
                               const CXIdxIncludedFileInfo *included_file) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:includedFile:)]) {
            return [parser.delegate classParser: parser includedFile: included_file];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

CXIdxClientASTFile importedASTFile(CXClientData client_data,
                                   const CXIdxImportedASTFileInfo *imported_ast) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:importedPCH:)]) {
            return [parser.delegate classParser: parser importedPCH: imported_ast];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

CXIdxClientContainer startedTranslationUnit(CXClientData client_data,
                                            void *reserved) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParserStartedTranslationUnit:)]) {
            return [parser.delegate classParserStartedTranslationUnit: parser];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

void indexDeclaration(CXClientData client_data,
                      const CXIdxDeclInfo *declaration) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:foundDeclaration:)]) {
            [parser.delegate classParser: parser foundDeclaration: declaration];
        }
    }
}

void indexEntityReference(CXClientData client_data,
                          const CXIdxEntityRefInfo *entity_reference) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        FZAClassParser *parser = (__bridge FZAClassParser *)client_data;
        if ([parser.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(classParser:foundEntityReference:)]) {
            [parser.delegate classParser: parser foundEntityReference: entity_reference];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processing at `#include` time may not be recorded since there's a lot of information there  (and there may not be required in the general case). There's a `createPreporcessingRecord` function which doesn't generate data if the option hasn't been enabled.

The Clang documentation describes [CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ggab1e4965c1ebe8e41d71e90203a723fe9a9e1dd69c4a2ff7954dca8df41a63c0e6) which you can use as a flag instead of the `CXTranslationUnit_None` which may help.